# Comparing DateTime Objects by Date Only in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, date, datetime, comparison

I’m working on a Flutter project where I need to compare two DateTime objects, but only by their date. The time component of the DateTime objects is not relevant for my comparison.

Here’s an example of the DateTime objects I’m dealing with:

> Dart

```dart
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.parse("2023-11-10 11:47:00");
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.parse("2023-11-10 10:09:00");
```

I want to compare dt1 and dt2 such that only the date (year, month, day) is considered, not the time. How can I achieve this in Flutter? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Be careful with solutions that do not properly consider timezone.  If you're comparing dates close to midnight, changing timezones may make them on the same day or different days.  So this question only makes sense with respect to some timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Flutter, you can compare two `DateTime` objects with respect to only the date (not time) by creating new `DateTime` objects from the original ones that contain only the year, month, and day information. Here's an example:

```dart
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.parse("2023-11-10 11:47:00");
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.parse("2023-11-10 10:09:00");

// Create new DateTime objects with only year, month, and day
DateTime date1 = DateTime(dt1.year, dt1.month, dt1.day);
DateTime date2 = DateTime(dt2.year, dt2.month, dt2.day);

// Now you can compare date1 and date2
if(date1.compareTo(date2) == 0){
  print("Both dates are the same.");
} 
if(date1.compareTo(date2) < 0){
  print("date1 is before date2");
} 
if(date1.compareTo(date2) > 0){
  print("date1 is after date2");
}
```

In this code, `date1` and `date2` are new `DateTime` objects created from `dt1` and `dt2` respectively, but they only contain the year, month, and day information. The time is set to 00:00:00 by default. Therefore, when you compare `date1` and `date2`, you're effectively comparing the dates only, not the times.

Comment: You can directly compare the year, month, and day of dt1 and dt2, why create new DateTime objects?

Comment: @Zhentao If you're testing for equality, then comparing is trivial without new `DateTime` objects.  A 3-way comparison is trickier, however, and it's quite easy to do it incorrectly.  Creating new `DateTime` objects is simpler and less error-prone.

Answer (score 2):

#### 1) Creating new Date objects using only year, month, and day attributes

```dart
final date1 = DateTime.parse('2021-09-01 03:30:00');
final date2 = DateTime.parse('2021-09-01 04:30:00');

int compareOnlyByDate(DateTime other) {
  return DateTime(date1.year, date1.month, date1.day).compareTo(
    DateTime(other.year, other.month, other.day),
  );
}

// usage
final result = date1.compareOnlyByDate(date2);

if (result == 0) {
  print('dates are equal');
} 
if (result < 0) {
  print('date1 is before date2');
}
if (result > 0) {
  print('date1 is after date2');
}
```

Or as an extension method:

```dart
extension CompareDates on DateTime {
  int compareOnlyByDate(DateTime other) {
    return DateTime(year, month, day).compareTo(
      DateTime(other.year, other.month, other.day),
    );
  }
}
```

#### 2) If you don't want to create new objects

You can compare `year`, `month`, and `day` attributes of your `DateTime` objects:

```dart
int compareOnlyByDate(DateTime date1, DateTime date2) {
  if (date1.year == date2.year) {
    if (date1.month == date2.month) {
      return date1.day - date2.day;
    } else {
      return date1.month - date2.month;
    }
  } else {
    return date1.year - date2.year;
  }
}
```

This is another way to do it:

```dart
bool isSameDay(DateTime date1, DateTime date2) {
  return date1.year == date2.year &&
      date1.month == date2.month &&
      date1.day == date2.day;
}

bool isGreater(DateTime date1, DateTime date2) {
  return date1.isAfter(date2) && !isSameDay(date1, date2);
}

bool isLess(DateTime date1, DateTime date2) {
  return date1.isBefore(date2) && !isSameDay(date1, date2);
}
```

Comment: great explanation.